# JNI: error Last 10 entries in JNI local reference table.

Tags: sqlite, java-native-interface

I am try to develop Native sqlite Lib which will help to access shA256 encrypted sqlite db. it is working while query result not big but if query result record count more then JNI returning error "Local reference table overflow 512 entries". Please check my code sample below.

jobjectArray rows=NULL;

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sdbquery, -1, &statement, 0) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    int cols = sqlite3_column_count(statement);
    int result = 0;
    jboolean flag = JNI_TRUE;
    int crow=0;
    jclass stringClass= (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String");
    while(1)
    {
        result = sqlite3_step(statement);
        LOGV("RESULT COUNT : %d\n", result);
        if(result == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            jobjectArray row = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, cols, stringClass, 0);
            int col;
            for(col=0;col<cols;col++)
            {
                jstring s = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, col);

                /*jstring valStr;
                if (val == NULL) {
                    valStr = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "");
                } else {
                    valStr = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, val);
                }*/
                //(*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, row, col, valStr);
                (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, row, col, s);
                (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env,s);
                //(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, valStr,val);
                //(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env,valStr);

            }
            if(flag == JNI_TRUE) {
                flag = JNI_FALSE;
                rows = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, count_rows, (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, row), 0);
            }
            (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, rows, crow, row);
            (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env,row);
            crow++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;   
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}else{
    LOGV("SQL error : %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return NULL;
}

(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, dbquery, sdbquery);
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, dbpath, sdbString);
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, dbkey, sdbkey);

sqlite3_close(db);
return rows;
```

Comment: Is there something here that can't already be done in Java via JDBC?

Comment: Not sure where you populate `count_rows`, but creating an array of String array objects is where you are blowing out the local reference count.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how you can construct a `jstring` object with a simple C cast. The line:

```
jstring s = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, col);
```

leads to memory corruptions, imho.

You should use:

```
const char* val = sqlite3_column_text(statement, col);
jstring valStr;
if (val == NULL) {
   valStr = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "");
} else {
   valStr = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, val);
}
```

be sure to the free the string, after the `SetObjectArrayElement` call, with:

```
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, valStr,val);
(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env,valStr);
```

When you query the class or your array of columns value, you don't free it.

Should be:

```
jclass rowClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, row);
rows = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, count_rows, rowClass , 0);
(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env,rowClass);
```

Also, as already seen in comments, you should double check your usage of `count_rows`.